# Kotlin coroutine called two times instead of once in Compose function

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack-compose

I am developing an Android app with Kotlin, Jetpack Compose - for UI, and Retrofit - for making requests to a REST API server made by me. I am a beginner at Kotlin Coroutines, Compose and Retrofit and I am facing the following issue:

- immediately after the HomeActivity starts, the assignSyncer() function in the HomeViewModel, which contains a coroutine that retrieves a Syncer object from the server via Retrofit, is called **two times instead of once**.

It does not produce any observable difference for the mobile user, but the server receives the request two times, and it is not ideal to burden the server and the network. I put some prints in the code and, indeed, the Retrofit call is executed two times - the code flows this way:

1. enters HomeActivity (CP_1),
2. enters assignSyncer() (CP_2),
3. launches coroutine (CP_3),
4. getInstance() is called (CP_4),
5. and the instance is created (CP_5) and the REST API call is made.

But immediately after, again,

6. CP_2,
7. CP_3,
8. and CP_4 are gone through.

The Syncer object is received correctly and it is integrated into the composable objects, even though this process happens twice.

Therefore, is it something I am doing wrong?

Here's some relevant code:

---

The HomeActivity which uses Compose:

```
class HomeActivity() : ComponentActivity() {

    private val homeViewModel by viewModels<HomeViewModel>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        println("CP_1")
        setContent {
            AppyTheme {
                HomeFrame(syncer = homeViewModel.receivedSyncer)
                homeViewModel.assignSyncer()
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Composable fun HomeFrame(syncer: Syncer) {
    /* ... */

}
```

The HomeViewModel:

```
class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {

    var receivedSyncer: Syncer by mutableStateOf(Syncer()) // Syncer() - initialises an empty Syncer object with default values for its fields

    var connectionError: Boolean by mutableStateOf(false)

    fun assignSyncer() {
        println("CP_2")
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                println("CP_3")
                val api = APIService.getInstance()
                receivedSyncer = api.requestSyncer(0L, 0L)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("CP_EXC - ${e.message}")
                connectionError = true
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The Retrofit call that receives a Syncer and the Retrofit instance:

```
interface APIService {

    @GET("base/sync/generate")
    suspend fun requestSyncer(
        @Query("fir-id") firstId: Long,
        @Query("sec-id") secondId: Long
    ): Syncer

    companion object {

        private const val BASE_URL = "http://192.168.1.4:8080/"

        private var apiService: APIService? = null

        fun getInstance(): APIService {
            println("CP_4")
            if (apiService == null) {
                println("CP_5")
                val gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()
                val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient
                    .Builder()
                    .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build()
                apiService = Retrofit
                    .Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build()
                    .create(APIService::class.java)
            }
            return apiService!!
        }
    }

}
```

The AndroidManifest file:

```
<!-- ... -->
<activity
    android:name=".ui.home.HomeActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Appy.NoActionBar" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<!-- ... -->
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your call to `homeViewModel.assignSyncer()` is a part of composition. So whenever there is a recomposition this function gets called. For such [side effects](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects), you should use proper effect handlers. Like here you want to call this function only once so you can use `LaunchedEffect` (refer linked doc for detailed information about these functions).

```kotlin
setContent {
    AppyTheme {
        HomeFrame(syncer = homeViewModel.receivedSyncer)
        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            homeViewModel.assignSyncer()
        }
    }
}
```

But there is still one problem with this code that it will call `assignSyncer` after every configuration change. Probably the best place to call this function is the `init` block of HomeViewModel.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Adding the LaunchedEffect() function resolved the problem. I haven't though written yet an init{ } block, but if the repeated calls will be back, I will implement it.

Answer (score 0):

In short: Never ever do this.

Compose functions must be side-effect free. Calling them multiple times should not cause problems. You should not make API calls just from drawing a composable. Check out the documentation for this: [Side-effects in Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects)

Composables can be recompositioned (redrawn). This causes your app to call `assignSyncer()` multiple times.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just had a vague grasp that the UI elements in Compose re-render at any change, but I did not think that this feature caused the unwanted effect.